# chartJS or/and php print_r not working together

Tags: php, laravel, chart.js, laravel-blade

So, i want to input data for the bar chart from a database, i got everything figured out, but something does not work...

Here's a part of the view file,

```
    var barChartData = {
      labels  : {{print_r($action_names, true)}} ,
      datasets: [
        {
          label               : 'Electronics',
          fillColor           : 'rgba(2, 24, 222, 1)',
          strokeColor         : 'rgba(2, 24, 222, 1)',
          pointColor          : 'rgba(2, 24, 222, 1)',
          pointStrokeColor    : '#c1c7d1',
          pointHighlightFill  : '#fff',
          pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(2, 24, 222, 1)',
          data                : {{print_r($action_count,true)}}
        }
      ]
    }
```

this does not work, it displays a blank chart.

The output from `{{print_r($action_names, true)}}` is `["OBJECT1","OBJECT1","OBJECT3"]`

and the output of `{{print_r($action_names, true)}}` is `[1,2,3]`

in the exact same formatting, now, if i just post the values in, as text, it works, the chart appears just fine, but when i use the variable, nothing - blank. I need to use the variable, because the database from which i fetch the data, is gonna change quite frequently.

Comment: The outputs of the variables where gotten by posting the lines in their own <div>  in the same view

Comment: Just echo the labels and data in chart variable.

Comment: Umm, how? i cant just type echo into the curly brackets, it does not  work that way.

Comment: Like. labels: [<?php echo trim($action_names);?>],
data: [<?php echo trim($action_count);?>],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `implode()` function to print your array data,

```
 labels : [ 
       {{implode(",", $action_names)}}
    ]
```

&

```
 data : [
      {{implode(",", $action_count)}}
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't to put a php function like this

```
labels  : {{print_r($action_names, true)}}
...
data: {{print_r($action_count,true)}}
```

try to isolate in a var

```
labels  : { {$action_names} }
...
data: { {$action_count} }
```

Comment: i put this into the controller     $action_names_out = print_r($action_names, true);
    $action_count_out = print_r($action_count, true); And still, nothing, everything is exactly the same, the output works just fine, but the  chart does not

Comment: I think that it may be something to do with the fact that the chart is in chartJS, and the part of code shown is inside a <script></script> but i am not sure, let alone i have no clue on how to fix it

Comment: now the part of the view we are taliking about looks like this  labels  : {{$action_names_out}} ,

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use the data in a script or something like that, you have to escape it, basically don't use {{something}} but use {!!something!!}

Answer (score 0):

Define new javascript array from existing php array using following syntax:

```
var labelValues = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $php_array).'"' ?>];
```

Comment: Thanks, but i solved the problem myself, i needed to escape the variable